# GWT SyncProxy Testing

Tags: gwt, testing, junit, rpc

I create a new Web Application Project with the standard GWT example. Then i want to test the greetingserviceimpl with the following test class. I don't know where is the problem. I also upload the project: http://ul.to/1pz1989y

```
public class RPCTest extends GWTTestCase {

@Override
public String getModuleName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "de.GreetingTest";
}

public void testGreetingAsync() {
    GreetingServiceAsync rpcService =  (GreetingServiceAsync) SyncProxy.newProxyInstance(GreetingServiceAsync.class,"http://127.0.0.1:8888/GreetingTest.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
    rpcService.greetServer("GWT User", new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {                
            ex.printStackTrace();
            fail(ex.getMessage());              
        }
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            assertNotNull(result);               
            finishTest();//
        }
    });
    delayTestFinish(1000);
}
```

}

Validating newly compiled units
   Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass. 
 
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors. 
   [ERROR] Line 17: No source code is available for type com.gdevelop.gwt.syncrpc.SyncProxy; did you forget to inherit a required module? 
[ERROR] Unable to find type 'de.client.RPCTest' 
   [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable 
   [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

Answer (score 0):

Your rpc service is async - it doesn't finish by the time that the testGreetingAsync method returns. GWTTestCase (but you are extending TestCase, you should probably change this) has support for this though - call `delayTestFinish` at the end of the method to indicate that the test is async. Then, call `finishTest` once you are successful.

```
public class RPCtest extends GWTTestCase {
    public void testGreetingAsync() {
        GreetingServiceAsync rpcService =  (GreetingServiceAsync) SyncProxy.newProxyInstance(GreetingServiceAsync.class,"http://127.0.0.1:8888/Tests.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
        rpcService.greetServer("GWT User", new AsyncCallback() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                //indicate that a failure has occured
                ex.printStackTrace();
                fail(ex.getMessage());//something like this               
            }
            public void onSuccess(Object result) {
                //verify the value...
                assertNotNull(result);

                //Then, once sure the value is good, finish the test
                finishTest();//This tells GWTTestCase that the async part is done
            }
        });
        delayTestFinish(1000);//1000 means 'delay for 1 second, after that time out'
    }
}
```

---

Edit for updated question:

> The test class 'de.RPCTest' was not found in module 'de.GreetingTest'; no compilation unit for that type was seen

Just like your regular GWT code must be in a `client` package, so must your GWTTestCase code - this also gets run as JavaScript so it can properly be tested as if it were in a browser. Based on the error, I'm guessing your EntryPoint, etc are in `de.client` - this test should be there too.

Comment: Thank you. But I have another problem. Is that possible to manage client session? Because the server side wants to know the name of the user which is saved as a String object in the HttpSession object.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you are even unit testing in a case like this - the servlet? If so, just make a normal test case and create a copy of the servlet? GWT-RPC itself? I'm pretty sure that works... By testing just the servlet, you can set up any other mocked session you want, and dont need to even deal with the GWT side. But the answer really is no: GWTTestCases run a special Jetty instance that you can't do much to interfere with, because that isn't the purpose of these tests.

Comment: Your solution above doesn't work. It is probably my fault. Have you tried this out? I think a working project with GWTTestCases that i can import would help me a lot. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you tried adding breakpoints to ensure that your rpc service works on the test jetty (i.e. did you add <servlet> lines in the test module)? see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting#DevGuideJUnitCreation under 'Client side Example' for more details on this - and update your question with any/all logs and new test that still doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help :-) I updated my question.

Comment: ok i corrected your improvements but there are unfortunately errors again. I inlclude the SynProxy.jar in the buildpath, so i wonder about the error "No source code is available for type com.gdevelop.gwt.syncrpc.SyncProxy; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped solve these problems.